# How to use two collections to authenticate zfcuser?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I use Doctrine and MongoDB ODM modules at my zf2 application. ZfcUser is used for authorization.

Is there a way to use two collections, say `users` and `clients` to authenticate via zfcuser+doctrine? I am curious, if there is a way to combine two mongo collections into one to use combined for authentication?

Comment: I have no experiance with envoirment You work with, but in pure mongodb You would just make two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to merge the users into one collection as you can have multiple 'authentication adapters' (see [`ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Authentication/Adapter/Db.php) for an example)

These are defined within global config file: `zfcuser.global.php`

Each of my adapters are run in order of priority until one returns a successful authentication result.

For example; I have the following configuration for `Users` and `Candidates` entities.

```
/**     
 * Authentication Adapters
 *
 * Specify the adapters that will be used to try and authenticate the user
 *
 * Default value: array containing 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db' with priority 100
 * Accepted values: array containing services that implement 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\ChainableAdapter'
 */
'auth_adapters' => array( 
    50  => 'JobboardCandidate\Authentication\Adapter\CandidateDatabaseAdapter',
    75  => 'JobboardUser\Authentication\Adapter\UserDatabaseAdapter',
    //100 => 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db', [this is the default]
),
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question you want to get one collection with two different document types so that you can use this collection for authentication.
If you use **doctrine Inheritance mapping** you can have two different classes and resolve them in one collection.
In this case your `Client` class would extend your `User` class. If you would use the `findAll` method in your `UserRepository` you would get both the clients and the users in one `Collection`

This will help you achieve what you want:

```php
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Document
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @DiscriminatorField(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "client" = "Client"})
 */
class User
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Document
 */
class Client extends User
{
    // ...
}
```

And then

```php
$userRepository->findAll();
```

Read more on inheritance mapping [here in the Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

Comment: Why do you mention Entity, ORM and so on? I use MongoDB Doctrine ODM. But ODM also has inheritance mapping - http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I thought you were using Doctrine ORM2. But I think you could indeed do the same with Doctrine ODM Inheritance mapping. The concept is exactly the same.